# Show that $A$ is a nowhere dense subset of $X$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ such that $X$ has no isolated points and each point of $A$ is an isolated point of $A$. Show that $A$ is a nowhere dense subset of $X$.

**Attempt**:

To show  $(\overline A)^{\mathrm{o}}=\emptyset$ .

Since each point of $A$ is an isolated point of $A$ so for each $a_i\in A$ we have $r_i>0$ such that $B(a_i,r_i)=\{a\}. $Surely $A$ is closed as it does not have any limit points.Hence $\overline A=A$.

Let $a\in A^\mathrm{o}\implies \exists r>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subset A$.

How to show that $A^\mathrm{o}=\emptyset $  from here??Any help.

Comment: A is not necessarily closed in X. As a counterexample, take $A=\{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, and $X= \mathbb{R}$. The fact that each point of $A$ is an isolated point of $A$ implies there is, for every $a \in A$ an $r>0$ such that $B(a,r) \cap A = \{a\}$.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment of M.Van says, $A$ need not be closed.

So consider $p \in \overline{A}$ and suppose there is some $B(p,r) \subseteq \overline{A}$. Then $q \in A \cap B(p,r)$ exists. As $q \in A$, there is some $s > 0$ such that $B(q,s) \cap A = \{q\}$ and as $B(p,r)$ is open we can find $s' \le s$ such that $B(q,s') \subseteq B(p,r)$. But $B(q,s') \neq \{q\}$  and so contains points of $A$ different from $q$. Contradiction.

Comment: Why is $s'<r$??

Comment: @MariosGretsas there is some $s'$ that works, and then take the minimum of that one and $s$ as the $s'$ we use. A smaller one also works.

Comment: I don't understand something..If $s' \leq s$ then $B(q,s') \cap A \subseteq B(q,s) \cap A= \{q\}$.How does $B(q,s')$ contain different points of $A$ other than $q$..

Comment: @MariosGretsas because the ball is not a singleton and lives inside $\overline{A}$.

Comment: A ok...thanks for your clarification..